# SQL Fetch data from another tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having following types of table

```
1. feeds ( id, user_id, type, object_id)
2. badge ( id, 'badge_name', 'slug' )
3. Post  (id, 'post_name', 'post_type')
```

I want to fetch all user feeds from feeds table on the basis of feeds type that is if feeds type is badge then object_id would reference to "badge" table and if feeds type is blog then object_id would reference to "Post" table in single query.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Currently I am doing this by the code and working as well. Just want to enhance it.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

use left join  and `coalesce` function

```
select f.*,coalesce(b.badge_name,p.post_name),
           coalesce(b.slug,p.post_type)
                    from feeds f
                    left join badge b on f.object_id=b.id
                    left join post p on f.object_id=p.id
```

Comment: @GhostRider what is the join key between feeds and badge table ?

Comment: Its a object_id  on the basis of type.

Comment: If type = badge then it will reference to badge table,
If type = blog then it will reference to Post table,

Comment: @GhostRider could you please create your table here and show me what error throwing it

Comment: There is no error yet, I want to fetch all the feeds and if type = blog then get Post(table) data and if type = badge then get badge(table) data respectively

Comment: @GhostRider yes this query will return that

Answer (score 0):

You should use `left join`, but the type of badge should be part of the conditions:

```
select f.*,
       coalesce(b.badge_name, p.post_name) as name,
       coalesce(b.slug, p.post_type) as type
from feeds f left join
     badge b
     on f.object_id = b.id and
        f.type = 'badge' left join
     post p
     on f.object_id = p.id and
        f.type = 'post';
```